# Access Violation between MDIChildren Interface: ShowModal TButton.OnClick of MDIChild1 to open MDIChild2 form

Tags: delphi

I have simple Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) here for MDI children interfacing using ShowModal example. But I have actually so many procedures that needs to interface between child forms.

Parent Unit

```
unit Parent_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TParentForm = class(TForm)
    mm1: TMainMenu;
    miOpenChild1: TMenuItem;
    miOpenChild2: TMenuItem;
    procedure miOpenChild1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure miOpenChild2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ParentForm: TParentForm;

implementation

uses
  Child1_u, Child2_u;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TParentForm.miOpenChild1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vChildForm1 : TChildForm1;
begin
  vChildForm1 := TChildForm1.Create(Self);
  miOpenChild1.Enabled := False;

end;

procedure TParentForm.miOpenChild2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vChildForm2 : TChildForm2;
begin
  vChildForm2 := TChildForm2.Create(Self);
  miOpenChild2.Enabled := False;
end;

end.
```

Child1 Unit

```
unit Child1_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TChildForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnOpenChild2: TButton;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure btnOpenChild2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ChildForm1: TChildForm1;

implementation

uses
  Parent_u, Child2_u;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TChildForm1.btnOpenChild2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChildForm2.ShowModal; // ERROR HERE: ACCESS VIOLATION
end;

procedure TChildForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Parent_u.ParentForm.miOpenChild1.Enabled := True;
  Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

Child2 Unit

```
unit Child2_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TChildForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ChildForm2: TChildForm2;

implementation

uses
  Parent_u, Child1_u;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TChildForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Parent_u.ParentForm.miOpenChild2.Enabled := True;
  Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

I am having trouble always with communicating between MDI child forms. What I have shown here is the simple error interfacing between child forms created for this purpose.

Is there a different approach for interfacing between MDI Children forms?

Comment: If you're gonna use the global variable in 2nd child unit, you must assign to the variable when you create the form. In "miOpenChild2Click" replace `vChildForm2 := TChildForm2.Create(Self);` with `Child2_u.ChildForm2 := TChildForm2.Create(Self);`

Comment: That doesn't mean there aren't any better approaches, yours is flawed: if you click the button on 1st child before selecting the menu item for the 2nd child, you'll get an AV.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Can you tell me where exactly my flaw in the code. I don't mind if the entire thing is flawed. I just need to know. Or can you suggest better approach.

Comment: What I think is flawed I already wrote, the part after the colon. I cannot suggest anything since I'm not familiar with the concept of MDI children that can be mutated into modal forms while being displayed normally..

Comment: You create `TChildForm2` and assign it to the variable `vChildForm2` (which is a local variable) in ParentUnit. There is no `ChildForm2` created in your code, and you're getting an AV when you try to access it because nothing is assigned to that variable. You should first be more careful about using global variables all over the place, and then you should learn to read your own code more carefully so you understand what it's doing. Turning on hints and warnings in the compiler will help immensely, but only if you read those hints and warnings and fix the issues they identify.

Comment: Your code is poorly written, BTW. You should never have to reference a parent form from a child it creates. Instead, the parent form should create the child, show it (especially when it's being shown using `ShowModal`), and then when the child is closed the parent can enable its own buttons and menu items (or actions) and free the child. And MDI isn't designed to work the way you're using it in the first place.

Comment: Why are you even calling ShowModal on a child form?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, my bad. It shouldn't be ShowModal. But the same thing happens when I tried to use 'Show' and any other command that will trigger event of another child form.

Comment: @KenWhite I'll go over with my codes with your notes and get back on this.

Comment: You don't show mdi children. They are always visible. So you don't call Show either.

Comment: @Juke this is the 3rd question you've posted recently that have all basically been a variation of the same core issue that has nothing to do with MDI itself. It is clear that you sinply don't understand how pointers work in general, and how to use them effectively. Especially the `Self` pointer. So I *strongly* suggest you stop what you are doing and go work on some tutorials that teach fundamentals of working with pointers, especially across unit boundaries. Come back to this project later

Comment: I think I figured out already what I want here. I don't have to make Child2 an MDI child. I should keep it fsNormal and have it called by Child1 button as ShowModal. This serves my purpose already. Thanks for all your inputs and guidance. I understand all your upsets here. Please bear with me. I am going to update now my question.

Comment: I suggest you to read the comments, you already have your answer.

Comment: @Juke: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to edit the solution into the question. If you found an answer to your problem and want to share, write an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: @Ken - AFAICS that was not an answer despite the confusing wording in the update text, just a slight variation on the question - one of the MDI children converted to be a normal form.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Look at the bottom of the post I rolled back, starting with *UPDATE*. It may not qualify as something that should be posted as an answer, but it's not an edit that belongs in the question either.

Comment: I have posted my answer with updated codes for others future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I am looking at accessing another form from fsMDIChild form type through a TButton. But, I realized, that the form to be accessed is another fsMDIChild would be more difficult and so many considerations to take.

I found the solution by keeping the form to access as a fsNormal form type instead of fsMDIChild. This practically serves my intention — limit access to other opened forms like the parent and child1 until normal form is closed.

Here's the updated code that works that works for me:

Parent Form of the ChildForm.

```
unit Parent_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TParentForm = class(TForm)
    mm1: TMainMenu;
    miOpenChild1: TMenuItem;
    procedure miOpenChild1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ParentForm: TParentForm;

implementation

uses
  Child1_u;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TParentForm.miOpenChild1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vChildForm1 : TChildForm1;
begin
  vChildForm1 := TChildForm1.Create(Self);
  miOpenChild1.Enabled := False;

end;

end.
```

Below the ChildForm that should access of the NormalForm through a TButton.

```
unit Child1_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TChildForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnOpenForm11: TButton;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure btnOpenForm11Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ChildForm1: TChildForm1;

implementation

uses
  Parent_u, NormalForm_u;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TChildForm1.btnOpenForm11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NormalForm.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TChildForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Parent_u.ParentForm.miOpenChild1.Enabled := True;
  Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

The normal form to be accessed here.

```
unit NormalForm_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TNormalForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  NormalForm: TNormalForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```